# no override found for 'vtkRayCastImageDisplayHelper'

Tags: image-processing, vtk, itk

I want to read series of DICOMs images and rendering them into a 3d volume. For this purpose I am using 
[this code](https://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/VolumeRendering/MinIntensityRendering) except that I used:

```
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader> reader =
vtkSmartPointer<vtkDICOMImageReader>::New();
reader->SetDirectoryName("ABEDINI^SHAHBEYGOM_1");
```

to read my DICOM series. I read DICOM successfully but in rendering step I have these Errors:

```
Generic Warning: In F:\VTK- 
8.1.0\Source\Rendering\Core\vtkRenderWindow.cxx,line 43   
Error: no override found for 'vtkRenderWindow'.

Generic Warning: In F:\VTK- 
8.1.0\Source\Rendering\Core\vtkPolyDataMapper.cxx, line 28
Error: no override found for 'vtkPolyDataMapper'.

Warning: In F:\VTK- 
8.1.0\Source\Rendering\Core\vtkInteractorStyleSwitchBase.cxx, line 43
vtkInteractorStyleSwitchBase (0000000000283740): Warning: Link to 
vtkInteractionStyle for default style selection.

Generic Warning: InF:\VTK_8.1.0\Source\Rendering\Core\vtkRenderer.cxx,line55 
Error: no override found for 'vtkRenderer'.
```

I added these lines befor main function:

```
#include "vtkAutoInit.h" 
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkRenderingOpenGL2); // VTK was built with 
vtkRenderingOpenGL2
VTK_MODULE_INIT(vtkInteractionStyle);
```

But now the error is:

```
Generic Warning: In F:\VTK- 
8.1.0\Source\Rendering\Volume\vtkRayCastImageDisplayHelper.cxx, line 20
Error: no override found for 'vtkRayCastImageDisplayHelper'.
```

What should I do? Any help would be welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was looking for vtkOpenGLRayCastImageDisplayHelper, in vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2.
By linking program to vtkRenderingVolumeOpenGL2 the error will disappear.