# Migration from vtk8.2 to vtk9.1 for qt application

Tags: qt, vtk, qvtkwidget

I have a qt5.12 application with vtk8.2 which uses QVTKWidget. Now I want to use vtk9.1 instead of vtk8.2. But vtk9.1 does not support QVTKWidget anymore. So, I just changed it into QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget and did not do anything more. I even compiled it (VS2015 update 3), but this application fails on the module "vtkFixedPointVolumeRayCastMapper.cxx" on the lines

```
  this->ImageDisplayHelper = vtkRayCastImageDisplayHelper::New(); // 1
  this->ImageDisplayHelper->PreMultipliedColorsOn();              // 2
```

because this->ImageDisplayHelper is nullptr after //1.
As far as I understood this is because "vtkRayCastImageDisplayHelper" is not registered.

So, how can I register it? Maybe, I'm completely wrong and should migrate to vtk9.1 in some another way?

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50774656/1717300 ?

Comment: Also, if you try to use `QVTKOpenGLNativeWidget` with vtk8.2, does that work?

Comment: QVTKOpenGLWidget  in 8.2. But I can't, there are a lot of errors.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/50774656/1717300  - no, i have another problem. Building and linking work good in my case

Comment: I was just thinking that that `::New()` might return nullptr also in case where there is a library or plugin issue.